# Accessing the memory location correctly to print the elements of an integer array using union in c

Tags: c, arrays, unions

I am not how to use the unions to print the integer array here. Please correct me to get the out.

val.str is being printed correctly - as '+100-100-100+760' and the first element of the output array seems to be loaded the value correctly. Then the same memory is overridden and printing some garbage value and this is something I don't know how to solve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

//Variable Decalartion
int i = 0, x = 100, y = -100, z = -100, p = 760;
int len_str;
char temp[4];

union Data{
   char str[16];
   unsigned int buff[8];
};

void Init(union Data val, unsigned int *dest);

int main(void){
   union Data val;
   unsigned int x[8];

   Init(val,x);
   for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
   {
     printf("0x%04X ",x[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}

void Init(union Data val, unsigned int *dest)
{
   len_str = sizeof(val.str);

   sprintf(temp,"%+04d",x);
   strcpy(val.str,temp);

   sprintf(temp,"%+04d",y);
   strcat(val.str,temp);

   sprintf(temp,"%+04d",z);
   strcat(val.str,temp);

   sprintf(temp,"%+04d",p);
   strcat(val.str,temp);

   printf("%s\n",val.str);
   printf("\n");

   for (i = 0; i < len_str+1; i += 2) 
   {
      val.buff[i / 2] = ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)val.str[i] << 8) |
                            (unsigned int)(unsigned char)val.str[i + 1];
      dest[i / 2] = val.buff[i / 2];                      
   }
}
```

The output that is displayed is,

```
+100-100-100+760

0x2B31 0x401111C8 0x8049A58 0x8048782 0x0001 0xBFFB5E74 0xBFFB5E7C  0x401B0E4D
```

Thanks,

Akhil

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, and do you expect an `int` to be two bytes?

Comment: Note: `char temp[4];` is too small for your `sprintf` operations. You should really use `snprintf` instead to avoid accidental buffer overflows. And bigger buffer size of course.

Comment: `char temp[4];` --> `char temp[5];`.....null terminator space needed

Comment: I am trying to use UART using DMA in an embedded application. For the same, i am converting my data in to ASCII type, and trying to send the same as integer type because DMA buffer needs in that format, like {'1','2','3'}.

Comment: Same for `char str[16];` --> `char str[17];`

Comment: Your `for (i = 0; i < len_str+1;...` is wrong, because it will do the last cycle with i=16, which accesses dest[i/2] giving index 8, which is out of range. More: perhaps, you want to convert _digits_ in numbers, not unsigned chars to integers? A digit you read "0", has a value of 48...

Comment: You pass `val` by value to the function. It seems like you were expecting to pass it by reference (i.e. changes in the function would affect `val` in `main`) .  In C to pass by reference you must pass a pointer to the object instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are many serious errors in this code.

As user694733 noted, `char temp[4];` is too small. you have a buffer overflow there.

You make this call: `Init(val,x);` with unititialized data in `val`.

Note that the `sizeof` `int` is platform specific. You seem to assume it is `16bits`?
It is `32bits` on PCs and modern ARM processors. But may be `16bits` on lower end processors.

Comment: *“This line likely returns zero.”* That’s not correct; `sizeof val.str` will always be 16, and is determined at compile time.

Comment: I corrected the buffer size of str[17] and temp[5] and initialized the val also. Still I am not able to get the out. I am using a dsPIC and where char is 1 byte and int is 2 byte according to dspic libaries.  for (i = 0; i < len_str+1; i += 2) loop runs 8 times as sizeof (val.str) = 16 previously as Ryan mentioned the value is 16.

Comment: Ryan: Correct. My mistake. Fixed now.